# Need assistance with Octal number subtraction

Tags: binary, numbers, octal

So I am trying to understand the difference between unsigned and signed octal number subtraction if the octal numbers were 6 bits. For example, octal 76 - octal 64:
I first convert 76 to binary which becomes 111 110 and 64 to binary which becomes 110 and 100:

But the problem is, if these octal numbers represent signed 6-bit octal numbers, would that mean the 111 110 is negative and 110 100 is also negative, meaning that the subtraction operator will cancel with the negative sign of the second octal number, resulting in an addition? Or do we just treat it normally, subtract the 2 binary numbers normally, and then look at the sign after?

Answer (score 0):

Your signed representation should not matter.

Take for example decimal -1, which in 6-bit octal would be 077 (representing octal with a 0 prefix, 2's complement representation assumed).

Then `077 - 077 = 000` , as expected. In binary, decimal -1 is `111 111`. But -(-1) is 1, which is octal 001. `077 - 077 = 077 + 001 = 000`, with overflow truncated.

You can also consider base 8 arithmetic directly. `076 - 064 = 012`. Instead of borrowing 10, as in decimal, you borrow 8. Consider `012 - 003`.  You borrow 8 from the 1 of 012 and add it to the 2.  `00{8+2}  - 003 = 007`.

If 076 is signed (assuming 2's complement), then in decimal, it is -2. Similarly, 064 in decimal is -12. The difference is `-2 - (-12) = 10`, which in octal is 012. No difference, whether signed or not.

The sign representation can be imposed after the arithmetic.